# Stylesheet alignment issue

Tags: asp.net, css, stylesheet

I am using the following code to display lables and checkboxes/textboxes in my MVC application.

```
<div style="width:auto; clear:both;">       
            <div class="metadata-left">Default Domain: </div>        
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.IsDefault) %></div>
            <br />

            <div class="metadata-left">Disabled:</div>
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.IsDisabled) %></div>
            <br/>

            <div class="metadata-left">Name:</div>
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.Name) %></div>
            <br />

            <div class="metadata-left">Domain Name:</div>
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.DomainName) %></div>
            <br />

            <div class="metadata-left">Forward Url:</div>
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.ForwardUrl)%></div>
            <br />

            <div class="metadata-left">Unsubscribe Url: </div>
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.UnSubscribeUrl)%></div>
            <br />

            <div class="metadata-left">Privacy Url:</div>
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.PrivacyUrl)%></div>
            <br />

            <div class="metadata-left">Brand Number:</div>
            <div class="metadata-right-domain"><%= Html.EditorFor(c => c.BrandNumber)%>
                <%= Html.HiddenFor(c=>c.Id) %></div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 0; text-align: center; padding-top: 4%; clear: both;" class="saveArea">
            <a href='' class="save">Save</a> or <a href="/Admin/EmailBlast/Domains" class="cancel">
                Cancel</a>
            <img src="/Content/img/loader.gif" style="display: none;" class="loading" />
        </div>
```

But I am not getting the alignment right. See picture:
[image]

This is the stylesheet I use:

```
.metadata-left
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    text-align: right;
     display:block;
}
.metadata-right-domain
{
    float: right;
    width:auto; 
    padding-left: 3%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

How can I get the right alignment?

EDIT: I display three DIVs side by side (one shown in the picture).

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. Please show your final markup and retag your question appropriately. Also I don't see why you have used the `jquery` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your DIV a width. Auto is not enough, so the div box is only as wide as the content. You can use % for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is a table. So just use `table` element to mark up this data:

```html
<style>
    .example TD {text-align: right; }
</style>

<table class="example">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Default Domain</th>
        <td>example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Disabled</th>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you need, you can place multiple tables side by side. For example, with `float` property:

```
<style>
    .example-tables TABLE {float: left; }
</style>

<div class="example-tables">
    <table>
        <!-- table 1 -->
    </table>

    <table>
        <!-- table 2 -->
    </table>

    <table>
        <!-- table 3 -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't that would work coz I display three such tables side by side.

Comment: You can place tables side by side if you need.